# Vue not rendering new data

Tags: node.js, dom, vue.js

I'm trying to use Vue and change a DOM, using informations that i got from a POST method.
I have a component named treeview:

```
<div id="treeview" class="col-sm-3" style="overflow-y: auto">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="file in files" v-on:click="openFile(file)">
      <i v-bind:class="file.filetype"></i> {{file.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And two functions to fill it up:

```
function ReadRede(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/ReadRede",
    success: function(datarec) {
      console.log(datarec);
      var filedropdown = new Vue({
        el: '#treeview',
        data: {
          files: JSON.parse(datarec)
        }
      })
      filedropdown.files = JSON.parse(datarec);
    }
  });
}

function ReadLocal(){
  var pathAtt = {
    path: localStorage.local
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/ReadLocal",
    data: JSON.stringify(pathAtt),
    success: function(datarec) {
      console.log(datarec);
      var filedropdown = new Vue({
        el: '#treeview',
        data: {
          files: JSON.parse(datarec)
        }
      })
      filedropdown.files = JSON.parse(datarec);
    }
  });
}
```

What is the correct way to make it change the DOM?

Comment: You shouldn't use vue like, inside your functions. Just initiate a new vue instance and put your logic inside methods or created() function

Comment: There's nothing wrong per se with instantiating Vue in a callback. In this case, however, I don't see anything that actually calls the functions that initiate the AJAX calls and certainly you don't want *two* Vues instantiating on the same element. One AJAX call will complete first and then `#treeview` will be gone and the second will fail. So, I expect some re-structuring is in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declared outside:

```
var filedropdown = new Vue({
  el: '#treeview',
  data: {
    files: JSON.parse('[]')
  }
})
```

And updated here:

```
function ReadRede(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/ReadRede",
    success: function(datarec) {
      console.log(datarec);
      filedropdown.files = JSON.parse(datarec);
    }
  });
}

function ReadLocal(){
  var pathAtt = {
    path: localStorage.local
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "/ReadLocal",
    data: JSON.stringify(pathAtt),
    success: function(datarec) {
      console.log(datarec);
      filedropdown.files = JSON.parse(datarec);
    }
  });
}
```

It's working, but is it corret?

Comment: You should only need `filedropdown.files = JSON.parse(datarec)`. Otherwise looks fine.